# Performance hit for having 2 mostly empty columns in a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a member table with around 20-30 columns.  We've recently added the following to allow accounts to be closed permanently

```
bool IsClosed
datetime DateClosed - nullable
varchar[100] PreviousEmail - nullable
```

At a guess maybe 1 in 10,000 members will ask to have their accounts closed.  This can only be done by request at the moment.

I think we should put the DateClosed and PreviousEmail into a separate table to denormalise the data. However I can tell other members of the team don't feel the same way and that it's just extra work and more complex queries introducing another join.

1. Is this a premature optimisation?
2. What kind of performance if we only ever hit max 5 million members?
3. Should I make the change when it becomes a problem and just crack on in the meantime

I'm inclined to make the new table now but I am conscious that I am too much of a perfectionist.

Comment: Small change, but you don't need IsClosed and DateClosed.  If DateClosed is NULL you know the account isn't closed.

Comment: It shouldn't impact your queries unless you are joining on those fields. There will be more data selected if you are doing `select *` which would slow things down, but I can't imagine you are running so close to the line that it would really impact you. More of a preference.

Comment: You might want to take a look at sparse columns since you think you might have 10k values out of 5M.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have no other boolean variables, this will increase the size of a non-closed member record by about 9 bytes (1 byte for `isclosed`, 8 for `dateclosed`, and none for for `previousemail`).  The additional columns could cause the null-bit array to be extended as well.

As noted in a comment, you don't need `IsClosed`, because you can presumably look at `DateClosed`.  There may be reasons to have the boolean.  For instance, for accounts might be re-opened or you might have a future close date stored in the record.

Adding these columns will be a hit on the database.  I would imagine a few minutes, because all the data does need to be rewritten -- fewer records will fit on a page, so adding the columns will probably cause page splits.  This is a one-time operation.  If you test it and then schedule it for Sunday at 3:00 a.m. (assuming that is a quiet time), there might be minimal impact on the system.

I would agree that the changes should be made directly into the table *if* you are convinced that this is the way to go.  Having a separate table with modifications to queries seems like a road to hairy, unreadable, difficult-to-maintain code.  A little baby nightmare just yearning to breathe free.

On the other hand, you might consider a separate status table.  This would have a member id, along with effective and end dates for membership status.  This could presumably go in-and-out of membership, and might have other states as well -- suspended, trial, or whatever.

Your queries would then need to incorporate this information, which you can do using various mechanisms, such as views and table-valued functions.